# Android: getting system services from within a application level library class

Tags: android

Hopefully someone can give me a pointer.  I have an application that makes several web service calls.  I'm in the middle of a refactor and I've pulled the actual calls out to a new class.  The problem is that I can't seem to use:

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
or 
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

within my class.  I'm not extending anything, so I suppose the problem is that I don't have the application context. Is there a good base class that I should be extending to be able to use these or some secret to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass application context to this new class' constructor.